# How to access any file (html) one level up to localhost path in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

[image]

How can I access the above file in image to the localhost:2000/dummy.html

and dummy.html is one level up to localhost?

Comment: if it could be i would

Comment: Show your express code so we can see things like what you have set up (if anything) using `express.static` etc. There are solutions for sure, but the obvious one is to put dummy.html into a directory that gets served via `express.static`. You need to show your code and, if relevant, explain why you don't serve it from a static dir.

Comment: i solved it by app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/path'));

Comment: @Trott but dummy.html is using its own css and images file so how to use them also ? localhost/dummy.html works fine but its doesnt making image path

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
__dirname + '../' + filename;
```

__dirname gives the path the script is executing from. Appending ../ + filename will tell node to look up one level in the directory path.

You should also look at the Process module in node. A lot of environment data is exposed through it. e.g. process.env.PWD also returns the current filesystem path.

Comment: but dummy.html is using its own css and images file so how to use them also ? localhost/dummy.html works fine but its doesnt making image path

Comment: You need to learn more about basic web architecture. The url paths the browser uses are relative to the domain name, not which directory the dummy.html is on the server. So whether you serve index.html or ../dummy.html, in the browser it will still just be http://domain.com/ or http://domain.com/dummy. If you wanted to load a logo jpg in both files, the url in the html would be the same, e.g. /static/img/logo.jpg. In your application you will have defined a route for /static/img/* that loads any matching file on that path.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to read the data of dummy.html, you can try:

```
fs = require('fs');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/dummy.html', function (req, res) {    
    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/../dummy.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

var host = server.address().address;
var port = server.address().port;

console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```